# Terminal - copy from CLI without using mouse

Tags: terminal, gnome-terminal, copy-paste

While firing commands in CLI, **I want to copy the command I just fired** or anything I wrote in terminal and **paste it somewhere else** without using mouse.

Like in following picture, I want to copy the update command (completely or partially) without using mouse and paste it somewhere.

[image: copy from CLI without using mouse]

Comment: You're using gnome without a mouse?

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`screen(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)  within your terminal emulator of choice (`xterm`, `gnome-terminal`, ...).

The functionality you need is built-in in `screen`. You need to get familiar with the way it works:

- by default, the "command" keybinding is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, you compose commands by issuing the "command" sequence plus the specific action.
- the "copy" command is:  <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>
- the "paste" command is <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>

You can "copy" the command and "paste" in another terminal.

`screen` is fun and once you start using it you'll wonder how it is possible you haven't been using it at all.

Comment: There was no `screen` command, so I installed it in gnome-terminal and started `screen` in a terminal. But couldn't get started thereafter. Also I didn't understand what you mean by built-in screen.

Comment: Read `man screen`. Also, I wrote 'built-in _in_ screen', meaning the copy/paste functionality is present in `screen` _by design_ .

Comment: You need to use `space` key to select desirable area.
You need to use `Y` to copy whole line or desirable area.
Screen is `vi` movements friendly.

Comment: what is `AltGr` key? I have `Alt`

Comment: I used `Ctrl + Alt + [` but not works.

Comment: The `screen` tool does not function has explained here. And it does not seem to provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the answers already provided, you could consider moving to a more flexible terminal emulator.

If you were prepared to change terminals to [rxvt-unicode](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/rxvt-unicode.html), you could use a tool like [urxvt-perls](https://github.com/muennich/urxvt-perls/): a collection of scripts that provide the following keyboard functionality in that terminal emulator:

- select, copy and paste text
- forward and reverse search
- highlight and open URLs in your preferred browser

You simply install the package and then add a few lines to your `~/.Xresources`, and you can then unplug the rodent for good.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using a program like `xclip`:

```
NAME
   xclip - command line interface to X selections (clip‐
   board)
```

Once you have installed it, you can use it to connect to your X clipboard. Unfortunately, this won't work in your `mysql` environment (it has its own buffer for copied lines) but it will if you want to run a 'normal' command. For example :

```
$ This is a long command line
```

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to go to the beginning of the line, enclose the command in quotes then echo it:

```
$ echo -e "This is a long command line" |xclip
```

You now have "This is a long command line" in your middle click clipboard.

If you want to paste without using a mouse, it will depend on where you are pasting. You can paste into another terminal by running:

```
$ xclip -o
```

You can paste into the same terminal, simply by killing (cutting) the command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> and then pasting with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>.

You can also save commands across terminals using bash's history. Add this line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a; history -r'
```

`PROMPT_COMMAND` is a special bash variable. If it is set the value is executed as a command before issuing a new prompt. `history -a` will write the history of the current session to the history file and `history -r` will reload that file. This means that every command you run will be immediately written to the history file.

Now when you run a long command line, you can switch to another terminal and hit return (just to run `$PROMT_COMMAND`, alternatively, open a new terminal window) and it will be accessible to this terminal's history. If you now hit <kbd>Up</kbd> you can run it on the new terminal.

Comment: That's ok, but I still have to use mouse?

Comment: @PrayagUpd ah, yes, that will copy to the middle click buffer. See updated answer for another way.

Comment: I think `$ xclip -o` is not what I want because it just prints what I `xclipe`d. But +1 for `Ctrl+A` followed by `Ctrl+K` and `Ctrl+Y` for cutting and pasting to the at least in the same terminal.

Comment: @PrayagUpd the thing is there are various clipboard buffers at play and the solution will depend on what exactly you want to do. Could you update your question with a specific example of what you need? I mean copying from where (mysql will be tricky) and to where.

Comment: Great `Ctrl+K` and then `Ctrl+Y` works within `mysql>` as well but I can't paste the same thing somewhere else neither in normal nor in `mysql` mode.

Comment: @PrayagUpd see updated answer for another trick.

Comment: I checked the updated answer and +1 for the trick.

Answer (score 2):

@evilsoup has suggested a good solution  but it breaks often.

### A Quick Solution

Here is a **solution that never breaks**.

```
history | tail -2 | head -1 | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Just run this command and it will copy the command you just ran to the clipboard.

Basically, what it does is that it prints your command history and takes the second last command and feeds it to your clipboard (the last command is this itself, so it selects the second last command).

### A Custom Function

Developing on the quick solution,here is a small function I wrote which is pretty smart and will copy the last used command. You can also provide numerical arguments to copy the last-nth command. E.g. for copying the second last command provide `2` as argument

```bash
myclipcopy () {

  if [ -z $1 ]
    then  # if no argument was provided then just copy the last used command
    history | tail -2 | head -1 | sed -re 's/[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+//g' | xclip -selection clipboard
    echo 'Anyways, the following command has been copied:'
    history | tail -2 | head -1| sed -re 's/[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+//g'

  else
    myindex=$(( $1+1 ))
    history | tail -$myindex | head -1 | sed -re 's/[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+//g' | xclip -selection clipboard
    echo "The following command has been copied:"
    history | tail -$myindex | head -1 | sed -re 's/[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+//g'
  fi

  #Delete this command itself from the history
  myhisnum=$(history | tail -1 | grep -oP '\s\d+\s' | grep -oP '\d+'); history -d $myhisnum
}
```

Copy-paste the above function in your `~/.bashrc` file. Note that if you put this in a separate bash script file, and run the script, it wouldn't work as the history command would not be able to access your history in that case.

Finally, run it as:

```sh
myclipcopy 3
# This copies the third-last command
```

Moreover, one cool feature added to this function is that it deletes itself from the history after it is run. This is helpful because then the "backward" index of the commands doesn't change.

Comment: This is not *robust*.

Comment: @mikeserv: I have renamed it now to "Custom Function". But why did you downvote it? Don't you notice that this properly answers the question? Moreover, why I said "robust" was because it actually should never break. By downvoting, you are just hiding an appropriate answer from the post.

Comment: I downvoted because you assume *a lot*: particularly bash and linux, neither of which are specified in the question. Also, your pipeline is ridiculously overcomplicated, and the same is true of your regex

Comment: @mikeserv: Thanks for the comment. Hopefully this will help me produce better answers. I will accept that my regex and pipelines are ugly. But they are well tested and I have been using it. And as for assumptions, did you notice that the highest rated answer had taken the assumption that the user was using `screen`. The second highest rated answer had also assumed `bash` and `linux`. Moreover, assuming `bash` is not a big deal because the script would still work find in zsh or most other shells.

Comment: I didn't say it was ugly - I said it was overcomplicated. And no, it won't work fine *in most other shells*.  And what's more, the *CLI* actually pictured in the question is MySQL. Good point about the other answers, though.

Answer (score 0):

This command uses bash's history expansion (so `!!` expands into the last line you typed into the terminal). You will probably have to install either `xclip` or `xsel`.

```
echo "!!" | xclip -selection clipboard

echo "!!" | xsel -i --clipboard
```

This will put your last command in the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> clipboard, so you will be able to paste in into any GUI program (or with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> in most terminal emulators, or with `"+p` in vim).

This will break for some lines containing double quotes, for example:

```
$ echo "foo;bar"
foo;bar
$ echo "!!"
echo "echo "foo;bar""
echo foo
The program 'bar' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install bar
```

It will work for the command you gave as an example though; you should only have problems if the double-quotes are escaping `;` `&` `&&` `|` `||` and so on.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this was the most practical solution I could immediately implement. And I believe the issues with " can be avoided simply by not quoting the !! at all, just do `echo !!` and it will work flawlessly (except in the improbable case that your previous command *began* with `-n` or `-e` or the few other options that `echo` itself takes).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most convenient solution but I use it and so it can be helpful for others more it doesn't require any additional soft installation.

1. You need to create a temporary file at any convenient directory
2. Transfer required direction or text to that file. For transferring direction you can use

   ```
   echo $(pwd) 1> tempo
   ```
3. To get direction from the file use command

   ```
   cd $(tail -n 1 tempo)
   ```

For copying and pasting commands this system will work either of course.
Hope that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
$ emacs -g '80x24' --eval '(term "/bin/bash")'
```

```
C-c C-k    char mode
C-c C-j    line mode
C-space    Selecting text in terminal without using the mouse
M-w        copy to X11 clipboard
```

where `C` = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and `M` = <kbd>Alt</kbd>.